# Django Migration Error with MySQL: BLOB/TEXT column 'id' used in key specification without a key length"

Tags: python, mysql, django

We have Django Model, use Binary Field for ID.

```
# Create your models here.
class Company(models.Model):
    id = models.BinaryField(max_length=16, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=12)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "company"
```

We use MySQL Database and have error when migrate.

```
  File "/home/cuongtran/Downloads/sample/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 270, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1170, "BLOB/TEXT column 'id' used in key specification without a key length")
```

Do you have any solution? We need to use MySQL and want to use the Binary Field for ID.

Thank you!

Comment: Just an advise from a lesson I have learned: Don't use binary primary keys. They are extremly uncomfortable to work with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you cannot achieve this. Based on Django documentation it looks like use of binary fields is [discouraged](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#binaryfield)

> A field to store raw binary data. It only supports bytes assignment.
>   Be aware that this field has limited functionality. For example, it is
>   not possible to filter a queryset on a BinaryField value. It is also
>   not possible to include a BinaryField in a ModelForm.
>
> Abusing BinaryField
>
> Although you might think about storing files in the database, consider
>   that it is bad design in 99% of the cases. This field is not a
>   replacement for proper static files handling.

And based on a [Django bug](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/2495), it is most likely impossible to achieve a `unique value` restriction on a binary field. This bug is marked as `wont-fix`. I am saying most likely impossible as I did not find evidence to confirm that binary field is stored as a `BLOB field` but the error does allude to it.

> Description
>
> When I used a field like this:
>   `text = models.TextField(maxlength=2048, unique=True)`
>   it results in the following sql error when the admin app goes to make the table
>   `_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1170, "BLOB/TEXT column 'text' used in key specification without a key length")`
>   After a bit of investigation, it turns out that `mysql` refuses to use unique with the column unless it is only for an indexed part of the text field:
>
> ```
> CREATE TABLE `quotes` ( \`id\` integer AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, `text` longtext NOT NULL , \`submitTS\` datetime NOT NULL, `submitIP` char(15) NOT NULL, `approved` bool NOT NULL, unique (text(1000)));
> ```
>
> Of course 1000 is just an arbitrary number I chose, it happens to be the maximum my database would allow. Not entirely sure how this can be fixed, but I figured it was worth mentioning.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL restricts the primary key on BLOB/TEXT column to first N chars,  when you generates migration file using Django's `makemigrations` command, `BinaryField` in Django is mapped to `longblob` which is BLOB column in MySQL **without specifying the key length**.

Which means your Django model definition :

```py
class Company(models.Model):
    id = models.BinaryField(max_length=16, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    class Meta:
        db_table = "company"
```

will be converted to SQL expression that causes this error (You can check out the detailed SQL expressions by `sqlmigrate` command) :

```
CREATE TABLE `company` (`id` longblob NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  `name` varchar(12) NOT NULL);
```

while the correct SQL expression for MySQL should be like this  :

```
CREATE TABLE `company` (`id` longblob NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(12) NOT NULL);
ALTER TABLE  `company` ADD PRIMARY KEY (id(16));
```

where `PRIMARY KEY (id(16))` comes from your `id` length in the BLOB column, used to structure primary key index of the table.

So the easiest solution is as described in the accepted answer -- avoid `BinaryField` in Django as primary key, or  you can manually add  raw SQL scripts to your migration file if you really need `BinaryField` (BLOB column) to be primary key and you are sure the `id` field will NOT go beyond the specific size (in your case, 16 bytes).